# Reverse the rotation of an animated gif and create a mirror image of it

Tags: image-processing, syntax, rotation, image3d, gif-format

I need Mathematica code to reverse the rotation direction and viewpoint of an animated GIF named "wheel." The current rotation is counterclockwise, and I need it to rotate clockwise while being a mirrored image of the original.

I've been working with this code provided by ChatGPT for hours, but I keep encountering errors. I've searched the forum, but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for. I'm attaching the animated GIF and giving you an idea of what I need. Also, it would be helpful to have some parameters in the code for resizing in case the result turns out too large.

Can you help me?

[image]

[Wheel.gif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zfr8LQAvnN4bHFrenHu9D2cNk5TfAM2o/view?usp=sharing)

```
(* Import the animated GIF *)
 originalGIF = Import["wheel.gif"];

(* Reverse the frames of the GIF to change the rotation direction *)
reversedFrames = Reverse[ImageData /@ ImageList[originalGIF]];

(* Create a mirrored version of the frames *)
mirroredFrames = ImageReflect[#, Left] & /@ ImageList[originalGIF];

(* Combine the reversed and mirrored frames to create the final GIF *)
finalFrames = Riffle[reversedFrames, mirroredFrames];

(* Export the final GIF with the reversed rotation and mirrored view *)
Export["wheel_reversed.gif", finalFrames]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To keep same speed for GIF import its "DisplayDurations":

```
dur = Import["/Users/Vitaliy/Desktop/wheel.gif", "DisplayDurations"]
```

And use it on export:

Start by flipping horizontally `ImageReflect` each frame:

```
originalGIF=Import["/Users/Vitaliy/Desktop/wheel.gif"];
finalFrames=ImageReflect[#,Left]&/@originalGIF;
Export["wheel_reversed.gif",finalFrames, "DisplayDurations" -> dur]
```

[image]

If you still need to reverse rotation - then reverse time. You reverse time by `Reverse` list of frames.

```
originalGIF=Import["/Users/Vitaliy/Desktop/wheel.gif"];
finalFrames=ImageReflect[#,Left]&/@Reverse[originalGIF];
Export["wheel_reversed.gif",finalFrames, "DisplayDurations" -> dur]
```

[image]

Now answering the comment question:

> Is it possible to insert a parameter that controls the size of the resulting GIF?

- For pixel size use `, ImageSize -> 400` option in `Export`
- For byte size check DETAILS section in [DOCS](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GIF.html), especially

[image]

-- those options affect byte size. `ImageSize` also affect byte size.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works quite well. Two things: a) Your result doesn't maintain the original GIF's speed. b) Is it possible to insert a parameter that controls the size of the resulting GIF?

Comment: @Pamela Happy to help. Please see updated answer. Please carefully review examples in doc page I linked.

Comment: hi, I can't move forward, I get this error, this is how the GIF is exported.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14AObWINVKU8z9AqpMG4Erc6EG2w1lsLy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Pamela the code works perfectly for me. You might be making some syntax mistake. Please check everything very carefully up to a coma, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a damn comma that wasn't there, but MMA didn't report it as an error. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 6):

- The idea is rotate the matrix(rotate `90 Degree`), that is

```
m = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {5, 5}];
m1 = Reverse[Transpose[m], {2}];
m2 = Transpose@Reverse@m;
MatrixForm /@ {m, m1, m2}
```

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"];
originalGIF = Import["wheel.gif"];
durations = Import["wheel.gif", "DisplayDurations"];
rotatedFrames = Image@*Transpose@*Reverse@*ImageData /@ originalGIF;
Export["test.gif", rotatedFrames, 
  "DisplayDurations" -> durations] // SystemOpen
```

[image]

- We can also use `ImageRotate` to rotation `90 Degree` or `-90 Degree`.

```
originalGIF = Import["wheel.gif"];
durations = Import["wheel.gif", "DisplayDurations"];
rotatedFrames = ImageRotate[#, -90 Degree] & /@ originalGIF;
Export["test.gif", 
  Rasterize[#, ImageResolution -> 15, RasterSize -> 250] & /@ 
   rotatedFrames, "DisplayDurations" -> durations] // SystemOpen
```

[image]

- And maybe `ImageTransformation` also work,but I can't figure out.

Comment: ,Hello, it's interesting to see it from the perspective of a matrix array. Why does your result have jumps? Can the resulting GIF be enlarged or reduced?"

Comment: @Pamela  I cut the gif to upload ,that is why the gif have jumps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't handle your matrix-based approach well enough

Comment: @cvgmt **Ad ImageTransformation** `ImageTransformation[#, TransformationFunction[{{0, -1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]] == ImageRotate[#, -90 Degree] &[originalGIF[[1]]]`

Comment: @vindobona Thanks!